# Diophantine equations in positive integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to know the solution of the equation $x^3$ + $y^3$ = $31z^3$ in integers.
I know the fundamental solution ($137, -65$, $42$), but want to have all the
values positive. I know also that there is an aritmetic procedure (doubling
in the group) to obtain further solutions from the fundamental one, but I
do not know the details of this procedure. Could you explain these details,
and how to get the first positive solution, in this case and in other cases
with fundamental non-positive solutions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don`t know a lot about this method, but it is part of elliptic curves.
The idea is to write the equation in two variables by making a change of
variables, r = x/z and r = y/z. Then if you have two rational points on the
new curve, you can draw a line through them and the line will intersect the
curve at a third point which represents the sum of the points, which is
also rational. If you only have one point, you can draw the tangent at that
point and the intersection will be a rational point (this is 'doubling' the
given point).

In your example you have the curve

$r^3$ + $s^3$ = 31

and a rational point r = 137/42, s = -65/42. If you draw the tangent at
this point and figure its intersection with the curve, you`ll get another
point

r = 277028111/119531076, s = 316425265/119531076

which corresponds to the solution of the original equation

x= 277028111, y = 316425265, z = 119531076.

Comment: @still I need more elaborated solution to deal my problem.

Comment: !How you got r and s values?

Comment: @gama!first read my solution carefully and then answer any number of questions does not matter.

Comment: !Thanks. I will contact you soon.

Comment: I need with figures. can you draw for me?

Comment: @Hello I need some pictures. kindly draw the tangent and tell me the solutions...